# Real time chat between website and app

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

We have social networking website which has a messenger module ( Chat with friends ) which is implemented in JQUERY, PHP and HTML with mysql. Now we are creating Mobile app of this Messenger module. So we decided to go to Ionic framework.

Now my problem is As we did R&D, We need to use GCM or FCM for smooth running of messenger with background service for real time chat and for push notification. 
So my query is, If we use GCM or FCM, And one user has app and another user on website, 
Then how they can communicate via GCM or FCM?

Another approach is we don't use GCM or FCM, Create REST API on server for Messenger app and call that API in background for messenger.

So which one is good approach?

If we use REST API then can you please share any example of this type, We are not able to find on google.

Please share your thoughts, We are struggling from last 7 days on this.

Comment: Use websockets ( bi-direction communication ) not ajax .

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use websockets

on the client side  [socket.IO](https://socket.io) is a godd library ) , you need to connect to a socket server ( in [php Rachet](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=php%20websockets&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) is a good one ) once the connection is open , you will basically have an exposed client side method ( function ) that the server can directly trigger.

eg: you have a chat window : two people connect 
1) person A sends a message to the server
2) The server receives this new messages, the triggers a broadcast to the socket server
3) The broadcast calls newMessage( messageText ) on the client ( Person B )
4) All the connected clients then display the new message

you can also have private channels ( for chat rooms )

This is a VERY high level description of my understanding of web sockets ( you should go and do some more research on websockets, but this is a starting point )

Comment: Thanks for info, But i want to save messages as well. For this we need to use nodeJs?

Comment: On the server when person A sends the message you will save this message to a database.
-- The server type is up to you really. node is a good socket server too